# Mean time to create ecumenopolis

Tags: science-fiction, space-colonization

We have fairly standard Sci-Fi scenario. Our human species somewhere near 2100s find ways of FTL travel and start colonizing galaxy. After some time they find also wormhole gateway connecting something of 100s of star system across half of galaxy. Of course knowing our adventure nature we can safely assume that we would be in no shortage of volunteer to colonize new frontiers. Also assume whole humanity is united in something more or less of confederation and there are no great external threats.

The thing I want in this scenario is some ecumenopolis, lets say 15 of them. **How long it would take to create and populate such planets in sizes from Earth to Moon?** 
I know it's impossible to give precise number, but at least i want to know it would take 100, 1000, 5000 or more years.

**EDIT:** 
By ecumenopolis I mean something similar to [Coruscant](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Coruscant) from Star Wars. It have population something around 1 trillion, I don't need actualy that high number, it could significantly smaller on moons and such, main thing is city covering whole celestial body on multiple lv

Comment: Can you define how large a population you would say "populate" your planets? Do you want roughly our 7.5 billion for an Earth sized planet? less? more?

Comment: You may want to include the definition of an ecumenopolis - it's a city that covers the entire surface of a planet or moon, like Coruscant from *Star Wars*.

Comment: Much more, take Coruscant for example, it have something of 1 trilion of inhabitants. I suppose 25% of it would still qualify, but to stay in this order of magnitude. Also I'll edit question to incorporate that info.

Comment: You want to create a city or you want to populate the planets? Becuase one of them will be faster than other. It took us to make 4,5 billions of people in 60 years. So we more than doubled the population while anything close to space big city is Tokyo.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the minimum time that it would take for an advanced species to create an ecumenopolis?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/141292/whats-the-minimum-time-that-it-would-take-for-an-advanced-species-to-create-an) (Oh hey, they changed the canned dupe-vote message. Didn't know they'd done that.)

Comment: To be honest? No. It operate in situation similar to our reality, like high child count per female, fertile age up to 50 and death in 100. This all would be totally alternated in advanced technological species, peoples would live for several hundred years and don't have that many children. And population isn't only thing, as I mentioned creating vast multilayered cities is main goal here.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume a trillion people equates to a world-wide city. Obviously this is highly dependent on the details of population density, life style, resources and much more but it’s a start.

Starting from 10 billion and doubling every 60 years means that it would take around 500 years to get to a trillion and another 500 years to get to 1000 trillion.

BUT there are so many assumptions any or all of which might derail that “estimate” which I will try to summarise below so I am going to say more likely 5000 years plus because:

The population might not oblige and double every 60 years – in fact it’s very likely it won’t in an affluent society.

There could be wars and if history is anything to go by there would be. This could slow growth depending on the severity.

People might well be attracted to the frontier and be less inclined to “bunch up” in world cities.

Once half the galaxy is starting to get populated and a few hundred years have passed what’s the chance that the other half of the galaxy or another galaxy becomes available?

The planets probably won’t play ball. Star Trek is all very well but the reality (if that’s the right word to use here) would likely be very different. Many of the worlds identified might be similar to the Earth astronomically speaking but they might or might not harbour life.

If they are barren the planet would have to be engineered or people would have to live in sheltered domes or similar and such processes that might well slow up the population growth rate greatly.

If there has been an alien biogenesis either people will have to live in domes as per the first case or risk confronting the local biota and this might cause a lot more problems than you might expect. The aliens will be perfectly adapted to their environment; terrestrial life won’t so the aliens will have the advantage. And both types of life forms are likely to be mutually incompatible and quite possibly toxic. Imagine [this](http://biochemical-pathways.com/#/map/1) selection of chemical reactions (use the arrows bottom right) has been twiddled with at the most basic level and is different beyond all recognition.

What are the chances that the resultant biochemistry will not throw up a range of unpleasant chemicals from a terrestrial perspective?

Finally some of the more developed locals might object to human invaders and fight them.

Comment: Not all people, most of them would pick living in luxury in post scarcity society on ever-growing ecumenopolis, where you can get all services you want in reasonable price. It wouldn't be "bunching up", using all three dimensions of space, you would get really high free space volume, especially when you are rich.